# missing package libc6-i386

Tags: debian

im trying to install darling on debian bullseye and am following the instructions they provide. when attempting to install the packages required one of the packages libc6-i386 fails to download returing a 404 error. I have attempted to just apt install libc6-i386 but still returns 404. both libc6:i386 and libc6:amd64 are installed. running apt install libc6-i386 returns the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hyphen-en-us lib32asan6 lib32atomic1 lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32quadmath0 lib32ubsan1 libreoffice-help-en-us mythes-en-us scrcpy-server
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,616 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libc6-i386 amd64 2.31-13+deb11u2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:6b::644 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-i386_2.31-13%2bdeb11u2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:6b::644 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

sudo apt update returns:

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                                                                      
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:4 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Hit:6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:5 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                                        
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

apt-cache policy libc6 libc6:i386 returns:

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-13+deb11u2
  Candidate: 2.31-13+deb11u2
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-13+deb11u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6:i386:
  Installed: 2.31-13+deb11u2
  Candidate: 2.31-13+deb11u2
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-13+deb11u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc' returns

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=====================================-===============================-============-=======================================================================================================================
iU  clang-9                               1:9.0.1-16.1                    amd64        C, C++ and Objective-C compiler
ri  gnome-session                         3.38.0-4                        all          GNOME Session Manager - GNOME 3 session
ri  gnome-session-bin                     3.38.0-4                        amd64        GNOME Session Manager - Minimal runtime
ri  gnome-shell-extensions                3.38.2-1                        all          Extensions to extend functionality of GNOME Shell
ri  gnome-sushi                           3.38.0-1                        amd64        sushi is a quick previewer for nautilus
ri  gvfs:amd64                            1.46.2-1                        amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - GIO module
ri  gvfs-backends                         1.46.2-1                        amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - backends
ri  gvfs-daemons                          1.46.2-1                        amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - servers
ri  gvfs-fuse                             1.46.2-1                        amd64        userspace virtual filesystem - fuse server
ri  initramfs-tools                       0.140                           all          generic modular initramfs generator (automation)
ri  initramfs-tools-core                  0.140                           all          generic modular initramfs generator (core tools)
iU  lib32asan6                            10.2.1-6                        amd64        AddressSanitizer -- a fast memory error detector (32bit)
iU  lib32atomic1                          10.2.1-6                        amd64        support library providing __atomic built-in functions (32bit)
iU  lib32gcc-s1                           10.2.1-6                        amd64        GCC support library (32 bit Version)
iU  lib32gomp1                            10.2.1-6                        amd64        GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library (32bit)
iU  lib32itm1                             10.2.1-6                        amd64        GNU Transactional Memory Library (32bit)
iU  lib32quadmath0                        10.2.1-6                        amd64        GCC Quad-Precision Math Library (32bit)
iU  lib32stdc++6                          10.2.1-6                        amd64        GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (32 bit Version)
iU  lib32ubsan1                           10.2.1-6                        amd64        UBSan -- undefined behaviour sanitizer (32bit)
iU  libclang-common-9-dev                 1:9.0.1-16.1                    amd64        Clang library - Common development package
ri  libsane1:amd64                        1.0.31-4.1                      amd64        API library for scanners
ri  libsane1:i386                         1.0.31-4.1                      i386         API library for scanners
ri  libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0:amd64            3.0.3-2                         amd64        TPM2 Software stack library - TSS and TCTI libraries
ri  libtss2-mu0:amd64                     3.0.3-2                         amd64        TPM2 Software stack library - TSS and TCTI libraries
ri  libtss2-sys1:amd64                    3.0.3-2                         amd64        TPM2 Software stack library - TSS and TCTI libraries
ri  libtss2-tcti-cmd0:amd64               3.0.3-2                         amd64        TPM2 Software stack library - TSS and TCTI libraries
ri  libtss2-tcti-device0:amd64            3.0.3-2                         amd64        TPM2 Software stack library - TSS and TCTI libraries
ri  libtss2-tcti-mssim0:amd64             3.0.3-2                         amd64        TPM2 Software stack library - TSS and TCTI libraries
ri  libtss2-tcti-swtpm0:amd64             3.0.3-2                         amd64        TPM2 Software stack library - TSS and TCTI libraries
ri  linux-image-5.10.0-10-amd64           5.10.84-1                       amd64        Linux 5.10 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ri  linux-image-5.10.0-12-amd64           5.10.103-1                      amd64        Linux 5.10 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ri  linux-image-5.10.0-14-amd64           5.10.113-1                      amd64        Linux 5.10 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ri  media-player-info                     24-2                            all          Media player identification files
ri  nautilus                              3.38.2-1+deb11u1                amd64        file manager and graphical shell for GNOME
ri  nautilus-extension-brasero            3.12.2-6                        amd64        CD/DVD burning integration for Nautilus
ri  network-manager                       1.30.0-2                        amd64        network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
ri  network-manager-gnome                 1.20.0-3                        amd64        network management framework (GNOME frontend)
ri  plymouth                              0.9.5-3                         amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer
ri  plymouth-label                        0.9.5-3                         amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - label control
ri  rhythmbox                             3.4.4-4                         amd64        music player and organizer for GNOME
ri  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder           3.4.4-4                         amd64        burning plugin for rhythmbox music player
ri  rhythmbox-plugins                     3.4.4-4                         amd64        plugins for rhythmbox music player
ri  sane-utils                            1.0.31-4.1                      amd64        API library for scanners -- utilities
ri  simple-scan                           3.38.1-1                        amd64        Simple Scanning Utility
ri  snapd                                 2.49-1+deb11u1                  amd64        Daemon and tooling that enable snap packages
ri  task-desktop                          3.68                            all          Debian desktop environment
ri  tpm-udev                              0.5                             all          udev rules for TPM modules
ri  udev                                  247.3-6                         amd64        /dev/ and hotplug management daemon
ri  udisks2                               2.9.2-2+deb11u1                 amd64        D-Bus service to access and manipulate storage devices
ri  upower                                0.99.11-2                       amd64        abstraction for power management
ri  xorg                                  1:7.7+22                        amd64        X.Org X Window System
ri  xserver-xorg                          1:7.7+22                        amd64        X.Org X server
ri  xserver-xorg-core                     2:1.20.11-1+deb11u1             amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ri  xserver-xorg-input-all                1:7.7+22                        amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ri  xserver-xorg-input-libinput           0.30.0-1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ri  xserver-xorg-input-wacom              0.34.99.1-1+b1                  amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ri  xserver-xorg-video-all                1:7.7+22                        amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ri  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu             19.1.0-2                        amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ri  xserver-xorg-video-ati                1:19.1.0-2                      amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ri  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev              1:0.5.0-1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ri  xserver-xorg-video-intel              2:2.99.917+git20200714-1+b1     amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ri  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau            1:1.0.17-1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ri  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                0.1.5+git20200331-1             amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ri  xserver-xorg-video-radeon             1:19.1.0-2                      amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ri  xserver-xorg-video-vesa               1:2.5.0-1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ri  xserver-xorg-video-vmware             1:13.3.0-3                      amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

Answer (score 0):

How did that happend? Some system relevant packages have status ri (for remove but also installed)

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

and create index for the repo's new

```
sudo apt update
```

then reinstall the following packages.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core udev
```

If his is running smooth

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

this reinstalles your current running kernel; because I do not know if your running kernel is also affected.

```
ri  linux-image-5.10.0-10-amd64           5.10.84-1                       amd64        Linux 5.10 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ri  linux-image-5.10.0-12-amd64           5.10.103-1                      amd64        Linux 5.10 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ri  linux-image-5.10.0-14-amd64           5.10.113-1                      amd64        Linux 5.10 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
```

the left over you can reinstall

```
sudo apt install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc' | awk '{print $2}')
```